# Filtering an array to populate a list

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, macos-big-sur

I have a `ObservableObject` with my data model, composed of the following struct:

```
struct Task: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var completed = false
    var priority = 2
}
```

A simple struct for a todo list within my app.

In the view in charge of building the list of tasks to display by priority, I would like to filter this data model by each element's `priority`, and display it on the list.

I'm still new to swift, but after some googling (and trying [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/dynamically-filtering-a-swiftui-list) specifically), I have tried:

```
struct TasksView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var taskdata: DataModel
    @State var byPriotity: Int
        
    // this of course fails. 
    let filtered = taskdata.tasks.filter { priority in
        return taskdata.$tasks.priority = byPriotity        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
      //...
    }
}
```

The idea is to pass `filtered` to the list and have that be displayed on the view. If the user selects a different button, then repeat, filter for the new priority and display.

How do I filter `@EnvironmentObject private var taskdata: DataModel` per `priority?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably make this a function on the `DataModel` rather than trying to do it on the `View`:

```
class DataModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var tasks : [Task] = []
    
    func filteredTasks(byPriority priority: Int) -> [Task] {
        tasks.filter { $0.priority == priority }
    }
}
```

And then in the `View`, it'd be used like:

```
var body : some View {
  ForEach(taskdata.filteredTasks(byPriority: byPriority)) { task in 
    //...
  }
}
```

If you really wanted to keep it on the `View`, you could do this:

```
var filteredTasks: [Task] {
    taskdata.tasks.filter { $0.priority == byPriotity }
}
```

Comment: That works, sort of. I think doing it at the DataModel level is good, I have a "sort" function there already. However, if I want to display ALL tasks regardless of priority is giving me issues.... How do you return all the `tasks` if, say, I pass `priority = 3` to show all?

Comment: What do you want to show in that case? All of them, or the ones with priority 3? Or do you want them sorted by priority?

Comment: All of them. Right now I have 0, 1 and 2. I really if I pass 3, all of them are shown. I tried to add an `if priority == 3 return the full array else .. your code` but it get all kinds of errors

Comment: You could do this: `tasks.filter { priority == 3 || $0.priority == priority }`